# Getting twice times true

Tags: powershell

Here is the script (saved in a file .ps1) :

I don't understand why I get true twice times ...

---

```
$MyCustomVar= "kuku"
if (get-variable -name MyCustomVar -erroraction silentlycontinue)
{   
    $true
    remove-variable -name MyCustomVar
}
else 
{
    $false
}

if (get-variable -name MyCustomVar -erroraction silentlycontinue)
{   
    $true
  #  remove-variable -name MyCustomVar
}
else 
{
    $false
}
```

---

At execution time of this script, I get twice times TRUE.

Thank you !

Comment: Are you sure? I'm getting `True` and `False`

Comment: I also get true and false. In my view `if (x) true else false` is an antipattern. Why not just replace it with `x`, in this case `get-variable -name MyCustomVar -erroraction silentlycontinue`?

Comment: That may sound a little bit crazy but which version powershell do you use ?
By the way im getting True and False also.

Comment: I am also getting True and False. If you're using PowerShell ISE, it stores variables in the session and across scripts. This means that if you reused the variable name in a test script, it could pull information from there. Please try this: copy your code, close PowerShell ISE, re-open PowerShell (doesn't have to be ISE) then paste in your code and run it. You should get True then False this time.

Comment: I also get true and false... Have you tried using the -force parameter?

Comment: Ok, it seems I've made a mistake by using the Powershell ISE. Now I get the good results. Sorry !